# Coercion to vector behaviour changes between R versions 4.1.3 and 4.2.0

Tags: r

I have observed the following changes in the R language. In R 4.1.3 I observe:

```
> tmp <- data.frame(var1 = c(0,1,2), var2 = c(3,4,5))
> as.vector(tmp[1,])
  var1 var2
1    0    3
> class(as.vector(tmp[1,]))
[1] "data.frame"
```

and now in 4.2.0 I observe

```
> tmp <- data.frame(var1 = c(0,1,2), var2 = c(3,4,5))
> as.vector(tmp[1,])
$var1
[1] 0

$var2
[1] 3

> class(as.vector(tmp[1,]))
[1] "list"
```

The coercion to the list led to a bug deep inside legacy code. I now have a fix (simply don't coerce my row) and am testing this more fully. I do see this is documented on this page [here](https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2021/12/07/upcoming-changes-in-r-4.2-on-windows/) as a breaking change and it indeed was very much breaking my code.

Curious if anyone is aware of the reason for this change, which I view as significant. Coercion to a type always led to the expected type in my experience. Of course, data frames are a list and always have been so perhaps this is consistent with the nature of a dataframe.

Comment: This is also documented in the [R 4.2.0 NEWS](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/NEWS.html) file.

Comment: Yes, and the `NEWS` entry explains the reasoning:  to make `as.vector(<data.frame>, mode="list")` work as you'd expect.

Comment: And to make `is.vector(as.vector(df))` return `TRUE`.

Comment: I'm mildly curious as well, but I still think it's off topic. Would the R-devel list be a better place for this?